# ESLint: First instance of let results in "unexpected token" error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

My javascript:

```
let foo = 'bar'
```

Why does ESLint respond with the following?

```
~/index.js
  1:5  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token foo

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

It seems like no matter where in the script, the first instance of using let to set a variable gets this error. Why??

My .eslintrc file:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "never"
        ]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answers about `let` being forbidden in the global scope are wrong. That's fine.

The problem is that you need to let eslint know you're using es6 features.

Do that by adding an `"es6": true` line to the `env` block in your config:

**.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            "tab"
        ],
        "linebreak-style": [
            "error",
            "unix"
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "never"
        ]
    }
};
```

That fixes your particular error, but you'll soon see errors about unused names. Below is the minimum source code I could find that will pass your eslint settings:

**let.js**

```
let foo = 'bar'

function main() {
  foo
}

main()
```

Comment: Thanks! I created the .eslintrc using "eslint --init" and I answered "yes" to the fact I was using es6 so it's odd that it didn't add that line.

Answer (score -1):

Variables declared with let are not accessible before they are declared in their enclosing block - so the first element will be undefined until the closing block is hit. If you are you defining foo in the global namespace, you will always get this error with using let in a loop.