# parsing error using 'let' possibly eslint related

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to use JavaScript to find the multiples of 3 or 5 for all numbers up to 1000 and then add them all up. I'm pretty confident about the actual math and whatnot in the code but for whatever reason I can't run anything because a parsing error keeps getting thrown up in the beginning. Here's my code:

```
let multiples = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {             
    if ((i % 3 === 0) || i % 5 === 0 ) {    
        multiples.push(i);                                                           
    }
    let answer = multiples.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
            return accumulator + currentValue;
        });
    console.log('the sum is ${answer}');
}
```

There's an error message on the first line. It reads: `ERROR: parsing error: unexpected token multiples`

I've looked around on other questions and I think ESLint plays a factor in it. I'm not sure what that is. I'm running the latest version of Brackets if that matters.

Comment: you surely want to use backtick instead single quote on `console.log`

Comment: What is giving you that error message?

Comment: And you probably want your `reduce` outside of the loop.

Comment: Curious. Is your ESLINT up-to-date?

Comment: [This SO question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40875615/eslint-first-instance-of-let-results-in-unexpected-token-error)

Comment: Actually, that might be out of date. If you have an .eslintrc file check to see if you have the following: `"parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 6 }`.

Comment: @Andy yes, that is the question I was referring to before. I can't seem to find any ESLINT files on my computer so I'm guessing that's why I'm getting an error